# Adding script references when editing code snippets

Tags: discussion

*This is semi-fictional: A question was edited and a script reference added, but it's not clear if this was the only problem (yet). It got me thinking about this issue though, so I thought I'd check what the collective stance is. I'll add the reference question in the end*

Should we, in general, add missing script references to code snippets in questions?

My current example:

Someone asked why their code was not working and posted a snippet without including the needed reference. This was (or could have been) the only thing missing to make the code work, and at the same time might have been the only answer to the question.

Someone edited the question and added the missing reference, in essence leaving the question pointless as it was now working. At the same time someone else (me) answered the question, suggesting to add the missing reference. This answer was now also pointless, and made no sense unless you went through the edit history.

If it's not clear already my opinion is that such edits should not be done, since it renders the question invalid/solved, but I might not have thought this through fully.

*For reference: [Open Span tag on image click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475080/open-span-tag-on-image-click/)*

Comment: Unfortunately, without an example, your question is not quite clear.

Comment: @JayBlanchard There is an example in the question. Is it required to be an actual event? Maybe I'm just bad at explaining. I'll see if I can improve it.

Comment: Since there is no link to the question it is hard to determine what you're talking about.

Comment: People should not be editing out typos from questions, no, especially if the question is about the typo. You can also close the question as "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. " if you have that ability.